# Converting JQuery to pure Javascript on submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, http-post

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to convert a functional jQuery script to pure Javascript. I tried but I failed. Overall I don't know how to "convert" '$.ajax...' in pure javascript language. Can somebody help me ?

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

            $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); 

                var $this = $(this); 

                var login = $('login').val();
                var nom = $('nom').val();

                if(login === '' || nom === '') {
                    alert('Fill the form correctly');
                } else {

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $this.attr('action'), // call webservice
                        type: $this.attr('method'), // method="POST" in the form
                        data: $this.serialize(), 
                        success: function(html) { 
                            alert('User added : success'); /
                            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/games_v3/"; 
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

I tried this but I don't know if it is correct so far ...

```
    var event = document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", waitfunction());

    function waitfunction(){
      event.preventDefault();
      form = document.getElementById(this);

      var login = document.getElementById("login");
      var nom = document.getElmentById("nom");

      if(login === '' || nom === '') {
          alert('Fill the form correctly');
      } else {
        [...]
      }
      }
```

Thank you for the help

New Edit : 
I tried this with the following in my form:

```
      <form onsubmit="return ready(fn);" [...]
```

And this brand new javascript:

```
     function ready(fn) {
       if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
         fn();
       } else {
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
       }
     }

     function fn(){
         var form = document.getElementById("form");
         form.addEventListener('submit', fn2(e));
     }

     function fn2(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
         var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
         if(login === '' || nom === '') {
             alert('Les champs doivent êtres remplis');
         } else {
             var form = document.querySelector('form');
             var data = new FormData(form);
             var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
             request.open('POST', './jeux/webservicesutilisateur/post', true);
             request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-                                 urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
             request.send(data);
             request.onload = function(html) {
                 if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
                   alert('Utilisateur ajouté avec succès'); // J'affiche cette réponse
                   window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/games_v3/";
                   var resp = request.responseText;
        }
             request.send();
      }
     }
     }
```

But still no alert box appears, so the javascript code doesn't seems to be functional...

Comment: You might also find this useful http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: That's what I use but nothing appears at 'submit' , the form is directly submited and the JSON is printed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey the same problem was faced by me in one of my projects. Below code snippet helped to make ajax call in pure javascript. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
/**
 *
 * @param url
 * @param method
 * @param data
 * @param callback (Callback function to handle response state)
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function makeAjaxRequest(url, method, data, callback) {
    var httpRequest;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        try {
            httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            try {
                httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
        console.log('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
        return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = (function () {
        return callback(httpRequest);
    });
    if (method && method.toUpperCase() == 'POST') {
        httpRequest.open(method, url, true);
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httpRequest.send(data);
    } else {
        httpRequest.open(method, url);
        httpRequest.send();
    }
}
```

** UPDATED CODE FOR FORM SUBMISSION **

```
function callbackHandler(httpRequest) {
    // response has been received so handle it now
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        //In case status is 200 is what you are looking for implementation
        // of this will change accordingly
        if (httpRequest.status >= 200 && httpRequest.status < 400) {
            alert("Posted form successfully");
            var resp = httpRequest.responseText;
            console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
}


(function(){
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
        var form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var login = document.getElementById("login").value;
            var nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
            if(login==='' || nom === '') {
                alert('Les champs doivent êtres remplis');
            } else {
                var form = document.querySelector('form');
                var data = new FormData(form);
                var action = form.getAttribute("action");
                var method = form.getAttribute("method");
                makeAjaxRequest(action,method,data,handler);
            }
        });

    });
})();
```

Comment: Hi @Samarth, thanks for your help. How do you call your function in your form , by using onsubmit="return makeAjaxrequest();" ?

Comment: Hi @JulesVercoustre I have updated code to call makeAjaxRequest() for form submit. Please mark it useful if it helps.

Comment: Your last update helped a lot, thank you a lot @Samarth :)